# Resizing ImageViews efficiently in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I'm making a scrollable view that contains images and edittexts below each image. The images shown below do not have the edittexts for simplicity. As a image is centered, it needs to "grow" and the image leaving needs to "shrink".

I'd like the images to resize as they become centered. I know how to calculate the sizes and positions in the view of each image as a function of scrollX. I have not tried to implement this, but I'd like to hear some opinions before trying to do this.

What is the best way to efficiently do this? 
Will it be computationally expensive to have 10 images (that will be the max) loaded and being constantly resized as the view scrolls? Will this be choppy?

Ideas:
- Calculate each image size and position upon the scrollX changing. Resize and reposition each image.
- Keep track of only the images that will be growing/shrinking as they are centered/leaving the center. Resize and reposition these as the view

Thoughts? What do you think would be the best implementation of this? Thanks!

[image]